# autofill text box from database value based on 1st textbox value

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to autofill values to textbox from database based on a value entered in a text box. I should get DOB as soon as i enter the name.

I tried following this example 
http://www.htmlblog.us/open-source/jQueryAutocompleteRelatedFields.html but i dont know why its not working for me.

Here is my code

html

```
<form name="appointment" method="post" action="apponiment_submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate()">
<table class="selection">

<tr><td colspan="3"><CENTER><font color="red"><strong>Fields Marked Star Are Compulsory</strong></font></CENTER></td></tr>
<tr><td>Patient Name  :</td><td><input type="text" name="p_name" id="p_name" /><STRONG><font color="red">*</font></STRONG></td></tr>

<tr><td>DOB :</td><td><input type="text" name="p_dob" id="p_dob" class="tcal" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            $('.p_name').autocomplete({
                source:'fill_patient_info1.php', 
                minLength:2,
                select:function(evt, ui)
                {
                    // when a zipcode is selected, populate related fields in this form
                    this.form.p_name.value = ui.item.p_name;
                    this.form.p_dob.value = ui.item.p_dob;
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

and in fill_patient_info1.php

```
// if the 'term' variable is not sent with the request, exit
if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term']) )

    exit;
 echo $_REQUEST['term'];
// connect to the database 
$dblink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db('hospital');


$rs = mysql_query('select patient_name,dob from patient where patient_name like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" order by patient_name asc limit 0,10', $dblink);

$data = array();
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'label' => $row['patient_name'] .', '. $row['dob'] .' '. $row['patient_name'] 
        );
    }
}

// jQuery wants JSON data
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
```

I am not well versed with json and jquery. So i am not getting where i am doing wrong.
Instead of `$_REQUEST['term'];` i tried putting `$_REQUEST['p_name'];` , but it did not work.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file `fill_patient_info1.php` you do not have to request term or p_name. You have to write down your full query, without the like condition. The jQuery UI auto complete will do the rest.
Your sql should then be:

```
select patient_name, dob from patient order by patient_name limit 10
```

UPDATE:
When you create the array, if you want to populate the dub too, you need to specifiy also the value like this:

```
$data[] = array(
        'label' => $row['patient_name'] .', '. $row['dob'] .' '. $row['patient_name'] ,
        'value' => $row['dob']
    );
```

Comment: @ Kiks: yeah ! i changed that and got only patient_name, not autofilling dob :(

Comment: Can you please suggest why its not taking :(

Comment: No, Actually its not working at all. after refreshing cache i checked it, its not happening. even the patient_name :(

Comment: Do you get any javascript error? Have you debugged in google chrome debugger?

Comment: No javascript error. Actually if i put ` alert('hello')` after `jQuery(document).ready(function(){
alert('hello')
`, Its not getting displayed. Its not connecting to script only :(

Comment: No :( The problem is its not entering to jscript only

Comment: I have made some changes in the script itself. And i made it work. Thanks for your time.