# autofill textbox with database values when 1st value is entered

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here i am linking the question and it is the continuation of that question [LINK IS HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007538/autofill-text-box-from-database-value-based-on-1st-textbox-value)

Actually i have made that work by changing the script like this

my javascript

```
       <script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function()
{ var ac_config = { source: "fill_patient_info.php", select: function(event, ui){ $("#p_name").val(ui.item.p_name); $("#p_dob").val(ui.item.p_dob) }, minLength:1 }; $("#p_name").autocomplete(ac_config); }); 
</script>
```

and in fill_patient_info1.php

```
$p_name = $_GET['p_name'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT patient_id, patient_name, dob from patient WHERE patient_name LIKE '".$p_name."%'"); 

$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
$p_name = $myrow["patient_name"]; 
$p_dob = $myrow["dob"]; 


$textout = $p_name.','.$p_dob; 
echo $textout;
}else
 {
echo "Sorry This Patient Does Not Exist";   
}
```

It is not working properly. If i have more than 1 name with the same letter, i cannot type in the 1st textbox. As soon as i enter the 1st letter it just fills up both the name and dob with the 1st patient name starts with that letter. after that i cannot delete and change that too.

Here is my input box for patient name and dob, which should be filled automatically(form)

```
<form name="consult" method="post" action="consult_submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate()">
<table class="selection">
<tr><td>Patient Name  :</td><td><input type="text" name="p_name" id="p_name" onkeyup="return filldetail()"  /></td></tr>

<tr><td>DOB :</td><td><input type="text" name="p_dob" id="p_dob" class="tcal" /></td></tr>
```

please suggest how to correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `onkeyup` you need to use `onblur`. If you use `onkeyup` event, the javascript function is called whenever you complete entering a charecter with keyboard. If you use `onblur`, the function will be called when you finish entering the text and change focus from the text field.

```
<form name="consult" method="post" action="consult_submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate()">
<table class="selection">
<tr><td>Patient Name  :</td><td><input type="text" name="p_name" id="p_name" onblur="return filldetail()"  /></td></tr>

<tr><td>DOB :</td><td><input type="text" name="p_dob" id="p_dob" class="tcal" /></td></tr>
```

Comment: Yeah! this is what i wanted! thank you. But can i do something that when i type a letter it will show all the names starts with that letter?

Comment: Yes. You can do it with AJAX. You will get the code easily if you search. If you don't get, let me know and will paste some reference links.

Comment: Can you please paste any reference link, which i can attach with my code? like this http://www.htmlblog.us/open-source/jQueryAutocompleteRelatedFields.html

Comment: Here is a link http://af-design.com/blog/2010/05/12/using-jquery-uis-autocomplete-to-populate-a-form/

Comment: it shows auto populating fields with data stored in the form of an array. You can replace that static array by dynamic data stored in your db.

Comment: I have used the same code in an old project ( a billing system for a small shop) to auto populate fields in billing page from stock data.

Comment: i am not getting how to attach this code to my code :(

Comment: you have to edit the demo_cities.php page and have to write the db connection and queries. Let me try making some changes in that code and paste it.

Comment: Please let me know once you read or copy the code I posted as answer so that I can delete it since it violates the SO policy.

Comment: you can remove the code. Thank you. But can you please check my javascript updated in the top. Bcoz, its not working. Nothing is getting displayed when i type

Comment: I have made some changes to the php codes in your question. Try now.

Comment: @ AeJey: i am not able to find any updated php file :( Its the same what i posted

Comment: `$p_name = $_GET['p_name'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT patient_id, patient_name, dob from patient WHERE patient_name LIKE '".$p_name."%'"); 


if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$p_name = $myrow["patient_name"]; 
$p_dob = $myrow["dob"]; 


$textout = $p_name.','.$p_dob; 
echo $textout;
}
}else
 {
echo "Sorry This Patient Does Not Exist";   
}`

Comment: actually, not any difference. i mean its not listing all the names when i type a letter